# Mi UPDATE con inputs dinámicos solo inserta la ultima linea - php

Tags: php, mysqli

Muy agradecido con cualquiera que pueda ayudarme. He intentado durante semanas insertar datos de dos entradas "inputs" generado dinámicamente, una con valor de texto y la otra con una referencia a la tabla.
El caso es que solo puedo insertar una línea, he probado varias configuraciones con mi código y no funciona.
Aquí está el código:

```
while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo"
    <li>        
     <h4>$pergunta </h4>
      <div class='col-12 col-12-xsmall'>
        <textarea cols='4' rows='3' name='seleccion[]' id='seleccion[]' 
            value='' placeholder='Escriba aqui a su respuesta.'>$resposta</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class='col-8 col-12-xsmall'>
        <input type='hidden' name='sele[]' id='sele[]' value='$id_pergunta' />
      </div>
    </li>";
                                    
}
```

En la parte php:

```
<?php

include("...");
 
$ativo   = $_POST['ativo'];
$id_resp = $_POST['id_resp'];

foreach ($_POST['seleccion'] as $resposta) {
}

foreach ($_POST['sele'] as $id_pergunta){ 

 $conn = "UPDATE Rest SET ativo='$ativo', resposta='$resposta'  WHERE id_pergunta ='$id_pergunta'";

 $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$conn);

}
?>
```

Comment: Puedes explicar como funciona y que es lo que quieres hacer, no comprendo bien la pregunta

Comment: Necesito hacer un UPDATE con en un banco, con el texto insertado en textarea y el id del input para localizar las lineas a actualizar de acuerdo con cada pregunta, el while genera  dinstintas preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en los `foreach`: el primero no hace nada y, el segundo, recorre las preguntas, pero no las respuestas.

Prueba utilizando los índices:

```
foreach ($_POST['sele'] as $i=>$id_pergunta){ 
    $conn = "
        UPDATE Rest SET 
            ativo='$ativo', resposta='".$_POST['seleccion'][$i]."'
            WHERE id_pergunta ='$id_pergunta'
    ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$conn);
}
```

No sé dónde cumplimentas `$ativo`, entiendo que sea el mismo valor para todas las preguntas.

Comment: Muchas gracias David JP, funcionó a la perfeccion. Saludos!!